# Is Tesseract(an OCR engine) reentrant?

Tags: concurrency, ocr, tesseract, reentrancy

I am doing OCR using Tesseract on a quad-core processor.
For better speed, I want to read 4 words at a time, using 4 threads.
Is it safe to call Tesseract from multiple threads concurrently?

Note: each thread will be working on a different, non-shared image.

Note: guarding with locks is not ok because of speed.

Comment: Code can be thread-safe without being reentrant. It sounds like you want thread-safety, not necessarily reentrancy.

Comment: Yes, it can be made thread-safe by using locks, but I need it to be reentrant, because of speed. The code should execute in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think tesseract is currently parallelizable (see [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/tesseract-ocr@googlegroups.com/msg01536.html)), although one of the [main goals for v3.0 is to make it more thread-safe](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ReleaseNotes).

However, you could always parallelize by running *n* concurrent *processes* of tesseract. If you want to parallelize the OCRing of a single image, it would be up to you to split it and feed each part to each of these *n* processes (basically a mapreduce).

Comment: Parallelization with processes will be much harder... I have a process that generates many different images at a time. Feeding these images to the tesseract processes is possible and will do the trick, but I will need a way to talk to the processes and to dispatch and collect the input/output.

Comment: @Hristo: I had exactly the same problem with GeckoFX and solved it with TPL + proxies: http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/03/proxying-and-parallelizing-processes.html

Answer (score 7):

From [the release notes](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ReleaseNotes), Tesseract is (mostly, and to the degree that you describe needing) thread-safe as of 3.01 (Oct 21 2011)

> Thread-safety! Moved all critical globals and statics to members of
>   the appropriate class. Tesseract is now thread-safe (multiple
>   instances can be used in parallel in multiple threads.) with the minor
>   exception that some control parameters are still global and affect all
>   threads.

I've been successfully using it on multiple cores for that long (or longer, from dev branch).